# ActiveXObject to download directly to HDD

Tags: javascript, jscript, activexobject, download

Is there a native ActiveX Object or similar that I can use to download a source file straight to my HDD. Currently I'm using the following:

```
function downloadToFile(url, file) {
    var xhr = new ActiveXObject("msxml2.xmlhttp"), 
        ado = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");

    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.send();
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        ado.type = 1;
        ado.open();
        ado.write(xhr.responseBody);
        ado.saveToFile(file);
        ado.close();
    }
}
```

But this feels a bit inefficient for a few reasons:

I'm currently using two objects in place of what could possibly be a single object.

The entire response is stored in memory until its wrote to file. This isn't an issue for the most part until I use it to download fairly large files.

**Notes/Edits**:
I'm working from within microsoft's MSScriptControl.ScriptControl so many web-based libraries will not help.

I'm not necessarily looking for a single object if an answer is able to write the data to file as it is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### BITSAdmin

[`BITSAdmin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362813.aspx) is a Windows command-line tool for downloading and uploading files using the [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) (BITS).

Note: In Windows 7, `BITSAdmin` states it's deprecated in favor of PowerShell BITS cmdlets, and may not be included in future Windows versions.

Syntax:

```
bitsadmin /transfer job_name url local_name
```

JScript version:

```js
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Run("bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png C:\\Work\\wikipedia-logo.png");
```

### .NET System.Net.WebClient Class

If you have .NET Framework, you can register the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class for COM access:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> regasm System.dll
```

and then use it like this:

```js
var strURL = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png";
var strFilePath = "C:\\Work\\wikipedia-logo.png";

var oWebClient = new ActiveXObject("System.Net.WebClient");
oWebClient.DownloadFile(strURL, strFilePath);
```

### Chilkat HTTP Library

[Chilkat HTTP ActiveX library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/HttpActiveX.asp) (commercial) lets you [download](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatHttpDoc.html#method008) files directly:

```js
var strURL = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png";
var strFilePath = "C:\\Work\\wikipedia-logo.png";

var oHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.Http");

//  Any string unlocks the component for the 1st 30-days.
var success = oHTTP.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial");
if (success != 1) {
  WScript.Echo(oHTTP.LastErrorText);
  WScript.Quit();
}

success = oHTTP.Download(strURL, strFilePath);
if (success != 1)
  WScript.Echo(oHTTP.LastErrorText);
```

### cURL

Or how about shelling out to [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (free, MIT/X derivate license)? Though I guess it counts as two objects because of `WScript.Shell`:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Run("curl -o C:\\Work\\wikipedia-logo.png http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png");
```

Comment: Im looking for a native windows object if possible

Comment: The update is a viable option, though I still feel there may be a better solution. If a more viable answer isn't presented you will get the bounty.